# Integration of Locust with Pytest

Tags: pytest, locust

I am trying to integrate pytest and locust and facing the issue PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class because it has a init constructor

```py
import json
import pytest
import requests
from locust import SequentialTaskSet, task

request_url = ""
module_name = "shifts"


class TestShifts(SequentialTaskSet):

    def get_shifts_data(self, login, request_data):
        global request_url
        name = "Get Shifts Data"
        request_url = login.get_base_url() + request_data['path']
        with self.client.get(request_url, catch_response=True, name=name, headers=login.get_header_get_request()) \
                as get_shift_response:
            if get_shift_response.status_code == 200:
                get_shift_response.success()
                return json.loads(get_shift_response.content)
            else:
                get_shift_response.failure("Get Shifts Failure")

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("login", "request_data")
    def test_delete_shift(self, login, request_data):
        global request_url
        name = "Delete Shift with name :" + request_data['requestBody']['name']
        shifts_data_dict = self.get_shifts_data(login, request_data)
        for shift in shifts_data_dict['shifts']:
            if shift['name'] == request_data['requestBody']['name']:
                with self.client.delete(request_url + "/" + shift['id'], catch_response=True, name=name,
                                        headers=login.get_header_get_request()) as shift_delete_response:
                    if shift_delete_response.status_code == 204:
                        shift_delete_response.success()
                    else:
                        shift_delete_response.failure("Shift Delete Failure")
```

Comment: Just a quick edit for the code formatting;  it looks like the code was split when it wasn't. ;)

Comment: Are you not missing a `User` class? see TaskSet docs: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html#tasksets